# How to get elements inlined in the header?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on creating a custom header. I'm not sure how to properly perfectly inline my elements in my header. For example, these elements should be where the red arrows are pointing:

[image]

How can I get these elements in the header, align them perfectly, and put them where the red arrows are pointing (picture above).

https://jsfiddle.net/af5caL8p/3/

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  height: 45px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: royalblue;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  line-height: 11px;
  display: inline-block;
}

button.signup {
  background-color: #2FA034;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
}


/* Material style */

button {
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: black;
  width: 130px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-size: 19px;
  background: royalblue;
  /* Ripple magic */
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1>Logo</h1>
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <button class="signup">Signup</button>
  <button class="signup">Login</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With `display: flex`. I updated your JS example: https://jsfiddle.net/af5caL8p/4

Comment: Take a look at this link: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

`display: inline-block` display simply makes elements with block/inline default properties use extra properties e.g a `<span>` by default an inline element and can only use padding and not margin.

Making it display inline-block allows it to use properties that apply to block elements such as a paragraph taking on margin.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  height: 45px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: royalblue;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  line-height: 11px;
  /*use flex instead of display: inline-block; explanation is above*/
  display: flex;
}

button.signup {
  background-color: #2FA034;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
}


/* Material style */

button {
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: black;
  width: 130px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-size: 19px;
  background: royalblue;
  /* Ripple magic */
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1>Logo</h1>
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <button class="signup">Signup</button>
  <button class="signup">Login</button>
</div>
```